# How faster is tensorflow-gpu with AVX and AVX2 compared with it without AVX and AVX2?

Tags: performance, tensorflow

How faster is `tensorflow-gpu` with AVX and AVX2 compared with it without AVX and AVX2?

I tried to find an answer using Google but with no success. It's hard to recompile `tensorflow-gpu` for Windows. So, I want to know if it worth it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your computation is one giant matmul on CPU, you will get 3x speed-up on Xeon V3 (see benchmark [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7257#issuecomment-277456370)). But it's also possible to see no speed-up, presumably because there's not enough time spent in high arithmetic intensity ops executed on CPU.

Here's a table from "High Performance Models" guide for training of resnet50 on CPU with difference optimizations. It looks like you can get 2.5 speed-up with best settings

```
| Optimization | Data Format | Images/Sec   | Intra threads | Inter Threads |
:              :             : (step time)  :               :               :
| ------------ | ----------- | ------------ | ------------- | ------------- |
| AVX2         | NHWC        | 6.8 (147ms)  | 4             | 0             |
| MKL          | NCHW        | 6.6 (151ms)  | 4             | 1             |
| MKL          | NHWC        | 5.95 (168ms) | 4             | 1             |
| AVX          | NHWC        | 4.7 (211ms)  | 4             | 0             |
| SSE3         | NHWC        | 2.7 (370ms)  | 4             | 0             |
```

If you are able to compile an optimized version for Windows, it would help to mention it in this issue -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues/13 , it seems there's some demand for such a build

Comment: Can you please describe your steps before you get error? I stuck on the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46140317/865475

Comment: sorry, I have no windows background. BTW, added table with timings for actual network

Comment: Note there's an issue here, I guess other people have trouble building this -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12978

Comment: cmake doesn't work also with error: `  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" e
xited with code 1. [C:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\cub.vcxproj]` (revision from the last successful nightly build)

Comment: Windows 10 also steals GPU memory. So, must die. I'm going to install Ubuntu.

Comment: much sadness :(

Comment: The master revision fails with another error using cmake: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" e
xited with code 1. [C:\tensorflow-cmake\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\gemmlowp.vcxproj]`

Comment: Cmake issue report: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12977

Comment: I checked both tensorflow with AVX and AVX2 support and without them. Performance difference is 0% (zero percent). By the way, my CPU is never loaded up to 100%. Everything works on GPU.

Comment: The question was about tensorflow-gpu, but this answer seems to quote some beanchmarks conducted on CPU-only training mode.